# Partitions appear larger than supposed to be

Tags: grub2, partitioning, resize, fdisk

I've resized my C:// (Windows7) partition by 41GB, hence made it smaller and Merged the extra space with the other Data Partition I had. Now Ubuntu is 'seeing' both partitions as larger when compared to how they are supposed to be.

The picture (link below) shows the comparison between Windows & Ubuntu, showing fdisk output as well.
Seagate & sdb is the other Hard Drive - it's unrelated.

[Windows & Ubuntu Partitions, and fdisk Output](https://mega.co.nz/#!fIUAgJjZ!PP3mlHfEnDmZcSAe_1LQ00G3NEZKyKc5lwCsJ8Tza2Q)

Anyone knows what's happening? And what should I do to make things as they are supposed to be?

Side-note: Boot-Repair and GRUB2 are also detecting 2 Windows7 Os's whilst I always had just one (and I never re-installed Windows or something of the sort). Dunno whether it's related.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: The picture download link does not work for Chrome browsers for some reason. Why don't you use some free image hosting service, like postimage or imageshack or so?

Comment: it IS supposed to work :S  ..Try this: https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1400455_10151764444286274_2060776871_o.jpg  ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you provided:
[image]
Ubuntu is telling you that you have:

- a partition with 251763712 blocks (keep in mind 1 KB = 1024 B) which is: 251763712 / 1024 / 1024 = 240.1 GB (which is the same what the Windows is showing)
- an extended partition, which contains 4 logical partitions (displayed also in Windows, with the following sizes: 650.3 GB, 3.862 GB, 16.06 GB and 21.07 GB), which has 724894720 blocks and total size of 724894720 / 1024 / 1024 = 691.3 GB. This should be equal to the sum of those 4 partition's sizes: 650.3 + 3.862 + 16.06 + 21.07.
- the first logical partition in that extended partition is your D: partition, which has 681897984 blocks of size 681897984 / 1024 / 1024 = 650.3 GB

So, everything is just like Windows has reported. The only thing that the Windows failed to report to you is that your 4 partitions (from D: to the right) are all grouped INSIDE one extended partition (due to the max 4 primary partitions limitation) and that's why Ubuntu is showing you the total size of all the logical partitions inside it (691.3 GB).

Using [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) (or PartedMagic) shows all of this in a nice graphical way, so please try it (just [make a bootable usb](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) with GParted on it and reboot your machine and use it).

Comment: Yes that I knew Mladen, as all you have to do is look at the start & end sectors. 

The thing that was 'worrying' me was that the partitions appeared larger (258GB AND 698GB) in Ubuntu (not 240GB and 691GB) .. turns out to be the way Ubuntu calculates disk size, as it uses Base-10 instead of 1KB = 1024 bytes. 
The other issue of having 2 Windows7 OS's was due to a BCD copied to C: by boot-repair as explained in other forum threads.

Thanks for your help as someone else might find it useful too ;)